# How to sort a list of date + time strings in Java

Tags: java, sorting, date, time

I have an array list of strings in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm". Is there any easy way to sort this list? Even if it is just sorted by the date that would be great

Comment: Write your own comparator

Comment: Convert the Strings to Calendar objects, sort th Calendar objects, then convert the Calendar objects back to Strings.